# Handling Authentication for a File Display using a Web Service

Tags: c#, jquery, json, angularjs, file-io

This is my first time developing this kind of system, so many of these concepts are very new to me. Any and all help would be appreciated. I'll try to sum up what I'm doing as efficiently as possible.

**Background:** I have a web application running AngularJS with Bootstrap. The app communicates with the server and DB through a web service programmed using C#. On the site, users can upload files and reference them later using direct links. There's no restriction to file type (yet), so just about anything is allowed.

**My Goal:** Having direct links creates a big security problem for me, since the documents/images are supposed to be private data. What I would prefer to do is validate a user's credentials when the link is clicked, then load the file in the browser using a more generic url path.

```
--Example--
"mysite.com/attachments/1" ---> (Image)
--instead of--
"mysite.com/data/files/importantImg.jpg"
```

**Where I'm At:** Not very far. My first thought was to add a page that sends the server request and receives a file byte stream along with mime type that I can reassemble and present to the user. However, I have no idea if this is possible using a web service that sends JSON requests, nor do I have a clue about how the reassembling process would work client-side.

Like I said, I'll take any and all advice. I'd love to learn more about this subject for future projects as well, but for now I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your first thought is correct, for it, you need to use the [Response object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and more specifically the `AddHeader` and `Write` functions. Of course this will be a different page that will only handle file downloads, so it will be perfectly fine in your JSON web service.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet? You're right, I can use AddHeader to set things like 'Content-Disposition', but most of the examples I can find are accessing a file path for their target file. How would this work over the web service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do this with a web service.  Just use a regular IHttpHandler to perform the validation and return the data.  So you would have the URL "attachments/1" get rewritten to "attachments/download.ashx?id=1".  When you've verified access, write the data to the response stream.  You can use the Content Disposition header to set the file name.

Comment: It's not a matter of whether I **want** to use a web service, my framework and project prerequisites actually require me to.

Comment: You are required to send the data to the browser as a JSON byte array? That is... unusual.